# convert integer to float /decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

the output should be as

```
totalsales

250.0000
```

code:

```
select cast(max (totalsales) as float())
from (select SalesPerson, avg(TotalSale) AS totalsales
from Sales 
group by SalesPerson);
```

current output is as 250.0 need as 250.0000

TotalSale datatype is integer

Table Sales:

```
InvoiceNo   SalesPerson TotalSale

1           Acheson      50    
2           Bryant       25    
3           Bennett     250    
4           Acheson      50    
5           Bryant      100    
6           Bennett     250
```

Comment: What is your problem/question?

Comment: There are two main ways to do what you need, and one of them is better than the other. The common advice is to use TO_CHAR on the numbers, so you can control the display. That is not entirely OK - since you are, in fact, changing the data type. For example, the numbers will now be aligned to the left instead of to the right. The other solution is to use your front-end's formatting capabilities **for numbers**, as illustrated in Mark J. Bobak's answer. That is the far superior approach to your issue.

Comment: Storage and presentation are two different things. As far as the database is concerned, 250, 00250, 2.5e2 and 250.000 are exactly the same thing. How you present them to the end user is something else.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be getting confused between what you see in your query tool and what the numeric data type result of the query is. If you want the output to have a particular appearance, format it:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(250, 'fm9D0000')
```

If you want to have a particular datatype, cast it (you seem to know how to do this) but don't assume it will look like anything in particular

If you're using a front end programming language to work with your data, don't use the database to format it; pull it numerically from oracle, and format it in the front end

Comment: Exactly; the result is 250; it is up to the presentation layer to format that value as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct average value I think you should cast the column value

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(totalsales), ‘0D0000’)
FROM (SELECT SalesPerson, AVG(CAST(TotalSale AS FLOAT)) AS totalsales
      FROM Sales 
      GROUP BY SalesPerson);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(value, '999.9999') from totalsales
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What client program are you using?

If SQL*Plus, try:

```
set numformat 999.9999
```

and then re-run your SQL statement.

If something else, you'll have to figure out how to format output in that client, and print your answer in the format you wish.